# Getting Segmentation fault: 11 while running gensim's Cosine Similarity function on a bunch of documents

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I'm using gensim to perform cosine similarity on a bunch of documents getting the Segmentation fault: 11. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

**Error Trace:**

```
2019-05-28 15:11:22,779 : INFO : creating sparse index
2019-05-28 15:11:22,779 : INFO : creating sparse matrix from corpus
2019-05-28 15:11:22,780 : INFO : PROGRESS: at document #0/546
2019-05-28 15:11:22,790 : INFO : created <546x430 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
        with 2191 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
2019-05-28 15:11:22,791 : INFO : creating sparse shard #0
2019-05-28 15:11:22,791 : INFO : saving index shard to /var/folders/s_/jrkppgc11h97hmtcs00cy6bc0000gn/T/simserver93714a.0
2019-05-28 15:11:22,791 : INFO : saving SparseMatrixSimilarity object under /var/folders/s_/jrkppgc11h97hmtcs00cy6bc0000gn/T/simserver93714a.0, separately None
2019-05-28 15:11:22,794 : INFO : saved /var/folders/s_/jrkppgc11h97hmtcs00cy6bc0000gn/T/simserver93714a.0
2019-05-28 15:11:22,794 : INFO : loading SparseMatrixSimilarity object from /var/folders/s_/jrkppgc11h97hmtcs00cy6bc0000gn/T/simserver93714a.0
2019-05-28 15:11:22,794 : INFO : loaded /var/folders/s_/jrkppgc11h97hmtcs00cy6bc0000gn/T/simserver93714a.0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**Code**

```
    def cosine_similarity(self,documents, query_docs=None, task='pairwise_similarity', metric_threshold=0.85, num_best=20):
        self.log('computing cosine similarity started')
        # Compute cosine similarity between the query_docs and the documents.
        dictionary = Dictionary(documents)
        corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in documents]
        # index_tmpfile = get_tmpfile("index")
        index = Similarity(output_prefix=None,corpus=corpus, num_best=num_best, num_features=len(dictionary))
        similarities = []
        if task == 'pairwise_similarity':
            self.log('computing pairwise_similarity')
            for sim in index:
                similarities.append(sim)
        elif task == 'batch_query':
            self.log('computing similarity using batch query')

            query_docs = [self.tfidf[self.dictionary.doc2bow(doc)] for doc in query_docs]
            for sim in index[query_docs]:
                similarities.append(sim)
        # filter results based on metric threshold
        filtered_results = []
        for ind_sim in similarities:
            filtered_results.append([item[0] for item in ind_sim if item[1] >= metric_threshold])
        self.log('computing cosine similarity completed')
        return filtered_results
```

Comment: I got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue, there was a problem with the feature representation I was using.